ViTMAE hidden states from encoder to a Unet decoder for binary semantic segmentation. (Huggingface ViTMAEModel)
I don't understand how to pass the hidden_states of the ViTMAEModel encoder into the Unet Decoder. I saw a visual on how a version of what I'm trying to do is done and it involves "reshaping". How do I pass in the hidden states? How do I reshape? Is it like the unpatchify function where I get rid of the cls token? What do I do with the CLS token?
from transformers import ViTMAEModel, ViTMAEConfig, ViTMAEForPreTraining, AutoImageProcessor
import torch
import torch.nn as nn 
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from PIL import Image

#No segmentation head yet

class MAEEncoderWithSkipConnections(ViTMAEModel):
    def __init__(self,config):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.config = config
        self.vit = ViTMAEModel.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base", config=config)
        
    def forward(self, pixel_values):
        
        outputs = self.vit(pixel_values, output_hidden_states=True,)
        hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states
        
        feature_maps = []
        patch_size = self.config.patch_size #unused
        img_size = self.config.image_size #unused
        
        print(hidden_states[2])
        for hs in hidden_states:
            hs = hs[:,1:,:]
            hs = hs.permute(2,0,1).contiguous()

            #print(hs)
            #num_patches_per_dim = img_size//patch_size
            
            print(hs.shape) #torch.Size([768, 1, 196])
            
            feature_maps.append(hs)
        return feature_maps

config = ViTMAEConfig.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base",mask_ratio = 0.0)

mae_encoder = MAEEncoderWithSkipConnections(config)

class UNetDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,config):
        super(UNetDecoder, self).__init__()
        #self.config = config
        
        self.up1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=768,out_channels=512,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
        self.up2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512,256,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
        self.up3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256,128,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
        self.up4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128,64,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
        self.out_conv = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1)
    
    def forward(self, skip_connection):
        
        x = self.up1(skip_connection[-1])
        #print(x)
        #print(x.shape)
        x = torch.cat([x,skip_connection[-3]],dim=1)
        
        x = self.up2(x)
        x = torch.cat([x,skip_connection[-6]],dim=1)

        x = self.up3(x)
        x = torch.cat([x,skip_connection[-9]],dim=1)
        
        x = self.up4(x)
        x = self.out_conv(x)
        print(x)
        return x
    
    
class MAEUnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,encoder,decoder):
        super(MAEUnet,self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
    
    def forward(self,x):
        skip_connections = self.encoder(x)
        output = self.decoder(skip_connections)
        return output
    

img = Image.open("/vast/home/mayolo/Downloads/mayolos_face.jpg").convert("RGB")
# Has Dataset STD and mean
processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained('facebook/vit-mae-base')


mae_model = ViTMAEModel.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base", config=config)
unet_model = MAEUnet(mae_encoder, UNetDecoder(config))

input_data = torch.randn(1,3,224,224)
input_img = processor(img, return_tensors="pt")

output = unet_model(input_img.pixel_values)

save_image(output,'outputimg.png')

Error:
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 512 but got size 768 for tensor number 1 in the list.
